# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons

I keep trying to build a simple app for my CST course but i keep coming across this very specific problem. The program itself does not seem to be the problem

I have rewritten the code three times already and that doesnt seem to be the problem. i have asked the TA and they also have no idea on how to fix this. I dont know what else to try so i hope one of you can explain why this is happening so that i can avoid it in the future

i have updated the question to contain my build.gradle file and the Build Output

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.daclink.gymlog_v_sp22"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    namespace 'com.daclink.gymlog_v_sp22'

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    def room_version = "2.4.3"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
29 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss apache commons-codec in your classpath.

if you use maven add

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.

Else download the jar and add it to your classpath